# Как произносится "Гнесинка", фамилия Гнесиных?

Tags: орфоэпия, фамилии

Твёрдо или мягко произносилась фамилия, когда жили братья и сёстры Гнесины? Какие предположения?

Просто я всю жизнь считал, что учебное заведение произносится твёрдо, и мама в этом уверена, а теперь на каждом углу вдруг слышу мягкое произношение Е и режет слух!

Answer (score 2):

Всё зависит от того, как сами сестры произносили свою фамилию. Такой подход универсален: когда речь идет о фонетике - носитель всегда прав. Но сейчас это установить вряд ли возможно. Допускаю, что старшее поколение поддерживает традицию. Но до конца принять эту версию мешает то обстоятельство, что в послереволюционные годы сложилась другая традиция, ничем вообще не оправданная: произносить все иностранные слова с ударным Е твердо: паштЭт, пионЭр и проч. Даже те, которые уже были обкатаны русским языком и требовали мягкого произношения. Это продолжалось до пятидесятых-шестидесятых годов.

Но если исходить из общих тенденций, думаю, что "гнЕсиных" как раз более правильно.
Гнесин - еврейская матронимическая фамилия, происходит от женского еврейского имени ***Гнеса*** (оно и сейчас встречается, но этимология его мне неизвестна).
Еврейские имена в русском очень быстро приобрели русскую фонетику, поэтому вероятно, что имя Гнеса/Гнеся (полная форма - Гинедл) и порожденная им фамилия произносились мягко.
Но опять же, как произносил свою фамилию сам Файвиша Иоселевич Гнесин (ставший впоследствии Фабианом Осиповичем), сказать совершенно невозможно.

Добавлю, что от музыкантов (хотя я и крайне мало с ними общался по причине свой абсолютной немузыкальности) вроде бы слышал оба варианта, но наверняка сказать не могу.

(+) Кстати об этимологии.
Я абсолютно отвергаю возведение к каким-то польским корням, равно как и встречающееся в сети - к греческому имени Агнесса, как совершенно невозможное. Во-первых, при чем тут поляки и греки, если идиш "от и до" построен на германской лексике? А во-вторых полная форма (Гинедл) - совершенно исключает подобные версии.

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересно!

Answer (score 1):

**Вопрос:**

Скажите, КАК ПРАВИЛЬНО ПРОИЗНОСИТЬ название колледжа: **ГнЕсиных или ГнЭсиных?** А то некоторые москвичи гордо щеголяют произношением **ГнЭсинка**. Это и есть правильный вариант? Спасибо заранее.

Модератор , 24-02-2007 в 11:57:16: Строгого правила здесь нет. **В подавляющем большинстве случаев – "Е"**

Если это заимствованное слово (скорее всего, фамилия Гнесин восходит к польскому gneisc – «толкаться, толпиться», «мяться»), то твердое произношение Э со временем часто смягчается. Вероятно, так случилось и здесь. (Также этому мог способствовать мягкий звук И во втором слоге.)

https://names.neolove.ru/last_names/3/gn/gnesin.html

https://zen.yandex.ru/media/starkids_who/kem-byli-gnesiny-chim-imenem-nazvano-muzykalnoe-uchilisce-6118be8b90c7e2078a6a6479

Comment: Спасибо, Шарон! Я всё-таки совсем не хочу привыкать к такому для меня совсем неестественному произношению.

Comment: Интересный вопрос!  Любопытно также, какова статистика  на текущий момент, тогда можно понять общую тенденцию. Многое зависит от круга общения. Часть москвичей настроена сохранить старое произношение,  но боюсь, что ее могут потеснить  другие пользователи, не имеющие тесных контактов с московским музыкальным обществом.